# If you start with 1 cell how many are at the end of meiosis?

Tags: meiosis

If you **start** with **1** **cell** how many are at the **end** of meiosis?

Can someone help me understand the process of what happens to the cells in the process of meiosis I and II

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Please ensure your post is [formatted correctly](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meiosis is a process of cellular division involving two consecutive cellular divisions. Unlike the other process of cellular division-mitosis it leads to twofold decrease in the number of chromosomes in the cell, e.g. there are half as much chromosomes in the nucleus of the cell as there were before the meiosis. But the cell undergoes 2 consecutive division so the answer to your question is **4**! There are **4 cells** at the end of meiosis.

There might be what some people would consider (exceptions) in some cases like in the mammalian ovogenesis (this is the production of egg cells) where the products of one of the cells produced by the first division don't develop and there isn't second division so the total number of cells is **3** but this is considered an exception, so the proper answer to your question is still **4**.

Comment: From [How do I write a good answer?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`*

Comment: What do you mean by that comment?

Comment: This question can be easily answered by a search on google.Please avoid writing answers for questions that do not have any research effort because they are off-topic